# The number of cache hits and cache misses in terms of L1, L2 and L3 caches

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

The following code will run on a CPU with the following cache structure:

- L1 cache: 1KB
- L2 cache: 8KB
- L3 Cache: 64KB
- Block size: 16B

  ```
   unsigned int A[65536];
   int i,j;
   for (i=0 ; i<65536-256 ; i++)
   for (j=1 ; j<128; j++)
   A[i]=A[i]+A[i+j];
  ```

I am studying for my midterm exam there is a question. Modify this code to minimise the number of penalties. Calculate the number of cache hits and cache misses in terms of L1, L2 and L3 caches.

I try to solve it via Loop Interchange. If I change to code like below, so there will be a sequential accesses instead of striding through memory every 16,364 word.

```
     unsigned int A[65536];
     int i,j;
     for (j=1 ; j<128; j++)
     for (i=0 ; i<65536-256 ; i++)
     A[i]=A[i]+A[i+j];
```

but I stuck with the cache hits and misses.
Can someone explain to me?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/74655/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43676711/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Your recent edit does not make any sense, aside from making the title meaningless and losing some information, shrinking your array makes the code access out of bounds. please fix or roll-back

Comment: @Leeor sorry some miss deleting happens. I convert it to beginning version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `unsigned int` is 4 bytes, the size of your array is 4 * 65536 = 256KB. Your L3 cache can only hold upto 64KB.

In order to minimize penalties, the first thing you should do is to break the loop into 4 sub groups, so that once you load an entry to L3, you should use it completely before being evicted.

```
unsigned int A[65536];
int i,j,k;
for (k=0 ; k<65536-256; k+=16384)
    for (j=1 ; j<128; j++)
        for (i=k ; i<MIN(k+16384,65536-256) ; i++) //define a MIN function to return minimum
            A[i]=A[i]+A[i+j];
```

Now to calculate cache hits and misses, a cacheline can hold 4 entries of the array. When you access A[0] for the first time, it will be a miss in L1, L2 and L3. When fetched from memory, you don't just fetch A[0], you will also fetch A[1], A[2] and A[3] as a cacheline can hold all 4 of them.

In the same instruction, you also access A[i+j], in this case will be A[1] which will be a hit. So it goes like,

```
First iteration
    A[i]   - A[0] - Miss
    A[i+j] - A[1] - Hit
Second Iteration
    A[i]   - A[1] - Hit
    A[i+j] - A[2] - Hit
Third Iteration
    A[i]   - A[2] - Hit
    A[i+j] - A[3] - Hit
Forth Iteration
    A[i]   - A[3] - Hit
    A[i+j] - A[4] - Miss // This will cause to fetch A[4], A[5], A[6], A[7]
```

An the pattern continues until L1 is filled.